# Git repository on a machine with a static IP

Tags: git, macos, osx-lion, static-ip-address, local-network

I want to have a Git repository for personal private projects.

I can host my server on my Ubuntu home computer but its IP (on the local network) is always changing so I can't reach it by SSH at any time from my Macbook. What's more, I always want to have a working copy available on my Ubuntu so that I can work on it just as on my Macbook.

Is there a way to do those two things ? (that's to say, making my Ubuntu's local (192.168.1.*) ip always the same and having the Mac directly push to the server updating the working directory ?)

Comment: The root question here is "How do I configure a machine to have a static IP on my home network", which is either SU or SF.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/) on both machines, and just push to your dropbox. Faster, easier, works anywhere, and still lets you back up onto your other server.

Answer (score 1):

here changing your IP Address setting for Ubuntu box from DHCP to Static IP would be helpful... there are several tutorials already available for it online, 1 fetched from quick google is
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/change-ubuntu-system-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address.html

after making this change, your Ubuntu box will always get the IP assigned as mentioned in the configuration made by you, and then you can access it over LAN without any problem.